# How should I store clothes to prevent animal damage and smell?

Tags: clothing, storage, moving

We are moving across a continent, and planning on staying with relatives until we rent an apartment or house.  As such, we decided to only keep a few items like clothes and computer, in a suitcase, and pack the rest of our household items in a container and have it shipped and stored until we are ready to move in somewhere.

Is it sufficient to pack clothes in cardboard boxes, pack the container, and expect no smell like mildew or insect or rodent damage to form?

The container is made of plywood with a waterproof seal on top, so it should stay dry and breathable (U-Box from u-haul)

We are moving to, thus the container will be stored in, Ohio, for at least 3 weeks, possibly up to 10.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not in a cardboard box. Keeping your clothes in a cardboard box makes it easy for pest maybe not to feed on but to rest and play around. Rather keep them in a safe place like cupboard. You can use naphthalene balls or maybe any soap bars to help odor.